# Displaying Unicode character cross-platform

Tags: c++11, unicode, ide

In my C++ code, I'd like to display "UpArrow" and possibly display it properly in MSVC/Xcode and maybe in Anjuta.

The character code is U+2191.

Trying to do:

ALT+2+1+9+1,

does not produce "UpArrow" inside MSVC editor.

Is it possible to display the symbol inside the IDE cross-platform?

Comment: `const wchar_t *UpArrow = L"\x2191";` or `const char16_t *UpArrow = u"\u2191";` then use `UpArrow` as needed in the rest of your code

Comment: Use CharMap or something to get the character, then paste it into the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You're really asking how to **type** the character, displaying it usually is not a problem.

If your keyboard layout has a Level 3 shift key (typically labelled `AltGr` on the physical keycap), press Shift+AltGr+u to produce ↑. Otherwise see https://superuser.com/a/78724/19948 – type `Compose, up, up` or `Compose, minus, circumflex` after installing the custom `.XCompose` file.